# How do I use the System namespace from the .NET Framework in Qt?

Tags: c++, .net, qt, serial-port

Specifically, I'm trying to use the [System.IO.Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.aspx) classes for controlling serial ports.   I am not sure if this is of any use at all: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-dotnet.html

I'm a bit lost here, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a strange thing to be trying to do. Are you writing a .NET application or a C++ application using the Qt framework?

Comment: C++ App using the Qt framework. However there is a .NET framework code I have that communicates with the serial ports, if there is no way to do this, I could probably use another library, however if you see that link above, there is .NET Framework Support with C++ and Qt, I'm just figuring out how to work it.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) has a great example for using the SerialPort Class.  Try this sample.  I believe this will get you on the track.

Comment: I'm trying to use it through Qt, and have not been successful